# JavaScript format a string like array object

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript I have a string like

```
Package=sdvasd&Qty=1&Price=34?Package=sdabhjds&Qty=1&Price=234?
```

I want to format that like an object array like this

```
[
{'Package' : 'sdvasd', 'Qty' : 1, 'Price' : 34 }
{'Package' : 'sdabhjds', 'Qty' : 1, 'Price' : 234 }
]
```

The code what I have tried so far

```
let packageData = data.split('?');
let packageArr = [];
if( packageData.length > 0 ) {
  for (var i = 0; i < packageData.length -1; i++) {
    let str = packageData[i].split('&');
    for (var j = 0; j < str.length; j++) {
      let keys = str[j].split('=');
      packageArr.push(keys[1])
    }
  }
}
console.log(packageArr);
```

But it is not giving me result like this. Can someone tell me how to make this like the desired output. Any suggestions and advice will be really appreciable.
I only want javascript method not jQuery

Comment: do you really have more than one question mark in the string?

Comment: @Nina Nobody said it's a URL query string… :D

Comment: @deceze, it was just a friendly remainder ... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the string and create for the outer splitting an array and for inner splitting the object and for the most inner splitting a key/value pair.

```js
var string = 'Package=sdvasd&Qty=1&Price=34?Package=sdabhjds&Qty=1&Price=234?',
    result = string
        .split('?')
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map(s => s.split('&').reduce((o, p) => {
            var [k, v] = p.split('=');
            return Object.assign(o, { [k]: v });
        }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `split`, `map` and `reduce`

```
var output = str.split("?") //split by ?
   .filter( s => !!s ) //filter out empty 
   .map( s => s.split( "&" ) //split by & and iterate each item
   .reduce( (acc, c) => 
          ( t = c.split("="), acc[t[0]] = t[1], acc) //split each item by = and set each key to accumulator and return the accumulator
   , {}) ); //initialize accumulator
```

**Demo**

```js
var str = "Package=sdvasd&Qty=1&Price=34?Package=sdabhjds&Qty=1&Price=234?";
var output = str.split("?") //split by ?
   .filter( s => !!s ) //filter out empty 
   .map( s => s.split( "&" ) //split by & and iterate each item
   .reduce( (acc, c) => 
          ( t = c.split("="), acc[t[0]] = t[1], acc) //split each item by = and set each key to accumulator and return the accumulator
   , {}) ); //initialize accumulator
console.log( output );
```

Comment: While nice, this is probably incomprehensible to @NewUser. :)

Comment: @deceze I have added more explanation inline.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have a question mark at the end of string. What about that? `Package=sdvasd&Qty=1&Price=34?Package=sdabhjds&Qty=1&Price=234?`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Also you can check for `number` values so that the `qty` and `Price` properties has numeric values and not string:

```js
var str = 'Package=sdvasd&Qty=1&Price=34?Package=sdabhjds&Qty=1&Price=234';

var resArray = [];
str.split('?').filter((obj)=>{
  var resObj = {};
  obj.split('&').map((item)=>{
    var itemSplit = item.split('=');
    if(isNaN(itemSplit[1])){
      resObj[itemSplit[0]] = itemSplit[1];
    } else {
      resObj[itemSplit[0]] = parseInt(itemSplit[1]);
    }
  });
  resArray.push(resObj);
});
console.log(resArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. Create a object and then put the key value pairs.

```
    let packageArr = [];
let packageDataArr = data.split('?');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(packageDataArr,(packageData)=>{
   let dataObj = {};
   let str = packageData.split('&');
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(str,(keyValue)=>{
      let keys = keyValue.split('=');
      dataObj[key[0]] = key[1];
   });
   packageArr.push(dataObj);
});
```